# How to iterate an array parameter in groovy

Tags: arrays, loops, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Lets say if we multiple envs like dev1, dev2, dev3, qat1, qat2, stg, prod and I have configured multiselect parameters in Jenkins Pipeline. 
I have saved the selected parameters in array

```
env = [ dev1, dev3, qat2]
```

How do I iterate these parameters one after one in below function

```
def DockerPush() {

def artifactory_repo_dev1 = "artifactory.dev1.com"
def artifactory_repo_dev3 = "artifactory.dev3.com"
def artifactory_repo_qat2 = "artifactory.qat2.com"


//Docker Tag
sh "docker tag " + "docker-example" + " " + "artifactory_repo_$env" + ":" + version


//Docker Push to Artifactory
    sh "docker push " + "artifactory_repo_$env" + ":" + "${version}"  
}
```

So that I will not have any duplication of code. 
Currently I'm using single select parameter and if else statements for all the selected environments which made my code about 500 lines . I want to minimize the code by using a for loop and iterate the selected parameters one by one.

Comment: you can use groovy itteration techniques to itterate an array

Answer (score 0):

Don't use local vars for such a task (note, that this can be made to work, like you want, but IMHO it's way to convoluted).

Instead use a map to store the relation between environment key and url.

E.g.

```
def chosenEnv = 'env1'
def envToUrl = [env1: "some.url.for.env1.com"]
def url = envToUrl[chosenEnv]
```

If your urls correlate directly to the env name, you can even generate the map:

```
def envToUrl = ["env1"].collectEntries{ [it, "some.url.for.${it}.com"] }
```

Comment: Should `def url = envs[env]` be `def url = envs['env1']` (note the single quotes and `env1` vs `env`)?

Comment: The first sentence vs the first line of code from OP made me pick a "better naming".  I'll clarify that

Comment: The change you made allows the code to work now.  The original code would not.